# How to send a Salesforce workflow outbound message to trigger a jitterbit 8.1 (full version) operation

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, jitterbit

I am currently evaluating Jitterbit 8.1 (Full version, 30 day eval).

In need to query SFDC for 4 custom field values from Opportunity records where Stage pickval ="...".

Each record must be POSTed as a single SOAP request to a 3rd party Web Service.

Cannot send more than 1 record to the 3rd party Web Service

Jitterbit (Full) is capable of querying SFDC records, but it defaults to sending multiple (all queried) within the Request file.

Although there is a chunking/record-limiting option at the operation level, (which should be configurable to send 1 record per file), it is grayed out for my SFDC query operation.

Was thinking that I could either send a Workflow triggered Outbound message to Jitterbit, or have an after-insert trigger do it for me (sounds better everytime I think about it).

How is the Listener created in Jitterbit?

Thanks in advance for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

Found:
http://support.jitterbit.com/documentation/How-to-Create-a-Hosted-HTTP-Endpoint

Attempts to explain how to create a listener, but completely misses on what url endpoint needs to be given to the outbound message though.  For testing purposes, will use:

- server name: YOUR IP ADDRESS
- port: 46908 if HTTP
- port: 46909 if HTTPS (authentication required)

Will set the WF rule & criteria, outbound message as action, and select the fields I want to send. Once saved, the WSDL can be stored (save target, save link as) to a .wsdl file, and imported into a Jitterbits' Web Service Method.

As per @solees, SFDC might send more than one record per outbound message, but the listener will handle them 1 by 1 by default.

Edit:
By popular opinion, the port appears to be 46908. 
According to @JimRae, the servername is the outside facing dns name or IP Address of your computer, or the one where the Jitterbit agent is running for this project !